# Java == operator works for list and set comparison but gives compile time error for String and StringBuilder comparison

Tags: java

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    if(list == set) {

    }
    String str = "test";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(); 
    if(str == stringBuilder){

    }
```

In above code list and set comparison doesn't give compile time error. So why does str and stringBuilder doesn't compile.

Comment: Related: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/193638/why-didnt-operator-string-value-comparison-make-it-to-java

Comment: Because `List` and `Set` are interfaces!

Comment: @BoristheSpider - That is neither necessary or sufficient.  The explanation is more complicated.

Comment: @StephenC it is not necessary, as one could be class. But is should be sufficient, no? As if both are interfaces, then it is always possible that a class can implement both.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Hmmm .... yes you are correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the intuitive explanation.

A `List` can be compared to a `Set` using `==`, because there *could be* classes whose instances are both lists and sets.

A `String` cannot be a compared to a `StringBuilder` using `==` because an object that is both a `String` and a `StringBuilder` is impossible.

---

However if you wanted to be able to compare `String` and `StringBuilder` using `==` you could do this:

```
String str = "test";
CharSequence chars = new StringBuilder(); 
if (str == chars) {
    // ...
}
```

Obviously, the above test will evaluate to `false`.  But it will compile.

This is legal because the type system says that `chars` *could be* a `String`.  Note that `CharSequence` is a supertype of `String` and `StringBuffer`.  (In this case, the supertype is an `interface`, but it doesn't *need* to be an interface.)

---

(Notes for other people encountering this question and wondering what the code is "trying to do" ... and the right way to do it.

1. It makes no sense to compare a `HashSet` and an `ArrayList` using `==`.  The `==` operator tests object identity, and no `HashSet` and `ArrayList` can ever be the same object.
2. It makes no sense to use `equals(Object)` either.  The javadocs state that a list can only be "equal" to another list.  Besides, comparing an explicitly ordered collection with an collection where the ordering is unstable is ... nonsensical.
3. The same applies to `String` versus `StringBuffer`.  They can never be `==` and they can never be equal according to `equals(Object)`.  If you wanted to compare a string and a string buffer character-wise, the simple answer would be `string.equals(stringBuffer.toString())`.

In short.  The code makes almost no sense ... *except* as an illustration of the OP's real question about how the typing works.)

Comment: Thanks Stephen, for awesome explanation!!

Comment: I think this answer should include the point that `==` is almost definitely _not_ what the OP wants. It only checks reference identity, not whether two different objects are equal. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: Except that `equals` won't work here either; see my update.